# Are these context free grammars equivalent?

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

The language is {w|w has an odd length} and the alphabet is {0,1}.

I came up with a solution of

```
S->1p|0p|e

p->00p|11p|01p|10p|e
```

and the book has

```
S->0|1|0S0|0S1|1S0|1S1
```

are these equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

They are not. The first grammar describes a language that includes the empty string; `e` should not be an option for expanding `S`.

Comment: if e was not included would they be equivalent?

Comment: @Programatic: They would.